Using V2DIP1-48?
I am trying send data (in the forms of int or strings) from a Teensy 4.1 via UART to USB (in my case, a Flash Drive). I am using a V2DIP1-48 to receive the data from the Teensy, convert it to UART, and write it to the flashdrive in the usb port.
I also have the necessary VNC debugger, that configures the chip. I am using a given example of UART to USB disc, included links below. There is just no file being created on the flash drive so I have no way to know if the data is being transferred. My Teensy 4.1 code is very simple but I also included it below.
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);    // USB serial for debugging
  Serial1.begin(9600);   // UART serial (Serial1) for V2DIP1-48
  delay(2000);           // Wait for initialization
}

void loop() {
  // String to send
  String dataToSend = "123\n";

  // Send the string over Serial1
  Serial1.print(dataToSend);

  // Print to Serial monitor for debugging
  Serial.print("Sent: ");
  Serial.println(dataToSend);

  // Wait before sending the next string
  delay(2000);
}

VNC Debugger: UART to USB
V2DIP1-48 Data Sheet

receive the data from the Teensy, convert it to UART ... isn't the Teensy outputting serial data? ... you would use a UART to receive the data ... if it is a UART to USB dongle, then the data would present at a serial port of the computer where the dongle is plugged in

Teensy 4.1 has usb host and can write to flash drives and sdcards, so I question what value is the v2dip adding? If you want a more complete system, then look at Zephyr - a complete RTOS with usb and filesystem support out of the box. I’m reasonably sure there’s a build for the Teensy 4.1. Nevertheless, teensyduino probably has all you need.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Some questions: (a) What file system is on the flash drive? The VNC2 documentation shows only FAT is supported. (b) Can you edit the question to include a schematic of how the Teensy is connected to the V2DIP1-48? The VNC2 documentation contains The default configuration of the UART port on the VNC2 is 9600-8-N-1, RTS_CTS flow control, and if no flow-control is configured on the Teensy you may be sending UART data before the VNC2 is ready to accept it.
